# UIWebView doesn't detect text box on website

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, passwords

I have a UIWebview that loads the e-mail website for my school. When you log in, you can view and read mail with no problem, but if you goto compose an e-mail or reply to one, you are unable to touch inside the message text box to write your e-mail.

I thought it was a problem with the actual e-mail client my school uses, but when I goto the website on Safari I am able to touch in the message box and write an e-mail as usual.

If you have any insight on why this would happening, i'd appreciate it!!

Also, I basically built my own web browser, how would I go about allowing users to save their user/password, for example for the e-mail link (I have other links to school related websites where it would be nice for it to save your user/pass).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MobileSafari (and `UIWebView`) don't support [`contenteditable`](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable), only normal `input`s and `textarea`s

Comment: Well like I said the message box is editable in MobileSafari but not in my custom UIWebView, that is why I am puzzled.

Comment: Would you have any idea why MobileSafari would detect the textbox but my UIWebView doesn't?