# How to load https (security) urls in UIWebView

Tags: iphone

I am loading http url's successfully in `UIWebView`, but while loading https url's blank screen is appearing. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427452/uiwebview-wont-load-links-with-certificate-https-prefix) and see if it works for you. Thanks.