# Unable to load HTTPS pages in UIWebView with redirection [iOS 9]

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, uiwebview, nsurlconnection

I am trying to load a **https://** webpage using `UIWebView` in iOS 9+ 
and it's giving following error :

> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802) CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9802)

I have already tried various mentioned approaches of using `NSURLConnection` first to handle authentication challenge using `connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:` method.

Although this is working fine for direct requests, **but** *(here the actual problem begins)* this is not working in case of webpages that redirect to another page with different domain.

So for instance, initially I load the `UIWebView` with call to *`https://example.com`* and this page then redirects to *`https://someothersecuredomain.com`*. This is were the connection fails and `connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:` is not called.

Below is my implementation :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Load webview with request url and parameters
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPBody:postBody];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    self.webView.delegate = self;
    [self.webView loadRequest: request];

    _BaseRequestURL = url;
}

#pragma mark UIWebView delegate
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if (![[request.URL absoluteString] isEqualToString:[_FailedRequest.URL absoluteString]]) {

        _FailedRequest = request;
        (void)[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - NSURLConnectionDataDelegate methods

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        NSURL *baseURL = [_FailedRequest URL];
        if ([challenge.protectionSpace.host isEqualToString:baseURL.host]) {
            NSLog(@"trusting connection to host %@", challenge.protectionSpace.host);
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        } else
            NSLog(@"Not trusting connection to host %@", challenge.protectionSpace.host);
    }
    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)pResponse {

    [connection cancel];
    [self.webView loadRequest:_FailedRequest];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"connection error : %@", error);
}
```

And here is the Connection error logged :

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred
>   and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x138643250 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred
>   and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
>   anyway?, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802,
>   _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure
>   connection to the server cannot be made., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction,
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
>   anyway?, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure
>   connection to the server cannot be made.}

As per iOS 9's **App Transport Security**, I have already added both the domains to the list of Exception domains in my `Info.plist`.

Which is like this :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
        <key>secure.ccavenue.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I am really stuck in this and any help would be appreciated.

PS. Already tried these questions : [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427452/uiwebview-wont-load-links-with-certificate-https-prefix), [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268230/has-anybody-found-a-way-to-load-https-pages-with-an-invalid-server-certificate-u), [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573164/uiwebview-to-view-self-signed-websites-no-private-api-not-nsurlconnection-i), [Question 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http) and [Question 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32560433/5060335)

Comment: Have you tried NSAllowsArbitraryLoads with a true value yet?

Comment: Tried, same error. Any other ways to get this working?

Comment: Did you solve the issue, @UditS?

Comment: @new2ios : No, we were not able to get a solution for this and eventually had to change the application flow.

Comment: 10x for reply, @UditS